# Magento2 : How to point sub domain?

Tags: magento2, multistore, subdomain

Hello I have website `test.english.com` in ENG language
I want to add new website view within it for Spanish language
For that, I have created Folder `magento_Root/pub/spanish` and point it.
Now the website is running on `test.english.com/spanish` perfectly.

- Now I want to change the domain for Spanish language is
  `test.spanish.com` So where I have to point new subdomain(I'm asking
  here folder path where to point new domain DNS).
- What i have to add in variable `$MAGE_ROOT`

So Spanish website will run on `test.spanish.com`.

> Server - Nginx (With CentOs) - Varnish Enable

Comment: I think if its website no need to create directory under pub you can simply add URL to associated website in configuration and redirection from htaccess will work. Same thing in apache working for me. No idea about nginx here you dont have htaccess as well. You can try add redirection into htaccess but if still not work you can contact hosting provider.

Comment: test.english.com/spanish  is working now i want it on other domain i have stated

Answer (score 2):

just add DNS record for the same ip address. add website code in magento,
and use `map` in nginx.

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
        test.english.com default;
        test.spanish.com es_ES;
}

map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_TYPE {
        test.english.com website;
        test.spanish.com website;
}
```

...

```
location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_param   MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
fastcgi_param   MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
}
```